# nginx web directory change

Tags: nginx, directory

I will change the web directory from /srv/http to /home/cseipel/webordner

But the problem is it don't work xD.
I don't find the bug in my config and systemctl restart ngnix is also not the solution.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen      localhost:80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
#            root /srv/http;
         root /home/cseipel/webordner;  
            index index.php index.html;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     #    root   /home/cseipel/web;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      root   /srv/http;
    #root   /home/cseipel/web;
      include        fastcgi.conf;
 }

 }

}
```

EDIT:

If i use localhost in Firefox the Error is: 403 Forbidden nginx/1.6.0
The index.php is include in the directory >.<

EDIT 2:

The output from systemctl status nginx

> ● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy
>   server    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service;
>   enabled)    Active: active (running) since Sa 2014-07-26 02:45:19
>   CEST; 15h ago   Process: 334 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g pid
>   /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) 
>   Main PID: 385 (nginx)    CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
>              ├─385 nginx: master process /usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr;
>              └─386 nginx: worker process
>
> Jul 26 02:46:41 myhost nginx[334]: 2014/07/26 02:46:41 [error] 386#0:
>   *1 "/home/cseipel/webordner/i...host" Jul 26 02:46:41 myhost nginx[334]: 2014/07/26 02:46:41 [error] 386#0: *1 open()
>   "/home/cseipel/webo...host" Jul 26 02:46:41 myhost nginx[334]:
>   2014/07/26 02:46:41 [error] 386#0: *1 open()
>   "/home/cseipel/webo...host" Jul 26 02:46:43 myhost nginx[334]:
>   2014/07/26 02:46:43 [error] 386#0: *1
>   "/home/cseipel/webordner/i...host" Jul 26 17:38:00 myhost nginx[334]:
>   2014/07/26 17:38:00 [error] 386#0: *2
>   "/home/cseipel/webordner/i...host" Hint: Some lines were ellipsized,
>   use -l to show in full.

Here is the output in a beautiful shape http://paste.debian.net/111790/ .

Comment: I believe you need to open up some permissions from your /home folder inwards in order to serve web sites out from a directory in there. Check out this article as a guide on what to change: http://bashingthenix.blogspot.com/2012/05/nginx-how-to-access-website-root-in.html.

Comment: Just rename directory and update nginx config root to new directory.